# HttpWebRequest WebException RemoteServer : Arguments:NotFound

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

First thanks for reading.
I have project .NET, the problem when I click menu.
I try to enable Windows Authentication 
and   to webconfig of Master Data Service. but still have this problem.

Error: " [HttpWebRequest_WebException_Remoteserver] Arguments: NotFound Debugging resource strings are unavailable.Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem.See http://go.rnicrosoft.com/fwlinkl?linkid=106663&Version=5.O.61118.O&File=System.Windows.dll&Key=HttpWebRequest_WebExcetion_RemoteServer "

[Imgae Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1J2l.png)

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/01d6c645-f757-40b7-98b2-18124c17ab96/debugging-resource-strings-are-unavailable-often-the-key-and-arguments-provide-sufficient?forum=silverlightdevtools

Comment: Have you had a look through [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/beatrice_popa/2013/01/31/master-data-services-issue-with-https-error-messagehttpwebrequest_webexception_remoteserver-arguments-notfound-debugging-resource-strings-are-unavailable/) article?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Thanks Everybody, i was edited post, pls help me find how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Hi Sandman, i was followed this post of Beatrice Popa and but can't fix this problem

Comment: hi Sankar Raj, i was added some code but nothing change.